# Ruby: Extract and operate on partially extracted Nokogiri objects

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = DATA.read
xml_nokogiri = Nokogiri::XML.parse xml

widgets = xml_nokogiri.xpath("//Widget")
dates = widgets.map { |widget| widget.xpath("//DateAdded").text }

puts dates

__END__
<Widgets>
  <Widget>
    <Price>42</Price>
    <DateAdded>04/22/1989</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
  <Widget>
    <Price>29</Price>
    <DateAdded>02/05/2015</DateAdded>
  </Widget>
</Widgets>
```

**Notes**:

1. This is a contrived example I cooked up as its very inconvenient to post the actual code because of too many dependencies. Did this as this code is readily testable on copy/paste.
2. *widgets* is a `Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet` object which has two `Nokogiri::XML::Element`s. Each of which is the xml fragment corresponding to the *Widget* tag.
3. I am intending to operate on each of those fragments with xpath *again*, but use of `xpath` query that starts with `//` seems to query from the **ROOT of the xml AGAIN** not the individual fragment.
4. Any idea why its so? Was expecting *dates* to hold the tag  of each fragment alone.
5. **EDIT**: Assume that the tags have a complicated structure that
   relative addressing is not practical (like using
   `xpath("DateAdded")`)

Comment: -1 because you have not edited your question with sufficient details. `xpath('.//DateAdded')` will search for a descendant `DateAdded` element at any level under the widget during each iteration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.//DateAdded` will give you relative *XPath* (any nested `DateAdded` node), as well as simple `DateAdded` without preceding slashes (immediate child):

```
- dates = widgets.map { |widget| widget.xpath("//DateAdded").text }

# for immediate children use 'DateAdded'
+ dates = widgets.map { |widget| widget.xpath("DateAdded").text }

# for nested elements use './/DateAdded'
+ dates = widgets.map { |widget| widget.xpath(".//DateAdded").text }

#⇒ [
#  [0] "04/22/1989",
#  [1] "02/05/2015"
#]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I missed to include an aspect: I can't use absolute targeting as the markup is pretty complicated & dynamic. Have updated the question to reflect it, thanks for your time anyways.

Comment: I am not sure I understood your comment. `DateAdded` in this context is **not** an absolute, but **relative to current node** _XPath_. Current node here is apparently `widget`.

Comment: I meant `widgets("//DateAdded")` is relative and `widgets("DateAdded")` is absolute. Even though your solution seems to work with this example, my markup is too complicated and dynamic to use absolute targeting. And moreover I am surprised why wouldn't the relative targeting work there.

Comment: Would you please finally understand: `widgets("//DateAdded")` is **absolute** while `widgets("DateAdded")` is **relative** and **not vice versa**.

Comment: I am terribly sorry you are right, I was thinking of one and typing the other. What I want is relative and not absolute. Will edit the question now. Sorry again.

Comment: Whether you want **relatives** please **re-read** my answer **carefully**.

Comment: `DateAdded` is not the same as `.//DateAdded`. If in the actual XML input, `DateAdded` is not an immediate child of `Widget`, the expression will fail to locate anything. `.//DateAdded` is what is needed most likely.

Comment: @MathiasMüller absolutely correct, thanks, will update an answer.

Comment: It's exactly the other way round I'm afraid. `DateAdded` for immediate children and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks @MathiasMüller @mudasobwa, I didn't quite understand that you are mentioning `.//`, have never used it before. Will read up.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I just can't find any resources that explains the behavior of `.//`, can you please provide some pointers to search for it?

Comment: Off-topic: Is there a way to convert the sub-nodes to independent nokogiri objects so that `//` can be used to parse them. I really don't get the idea of the full document being present in the individual objects after being parsed.

Comment: The specification that applies is http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/, XPath 1.0. Nokogiri uses libxml2, which only supports XPath 1.0. Apologies for being nit-picking!

Comment: @MathiasMüller Yes, you are right again; being sure that `.//` path was introduced from the very beginning I superficially googled for `w3c xpath ".//"` and came with first reference.